# Aosp Download Issue

Tags: android-source

When i have downloaded android 10.0.0_r1  aosp code from the android source it took almost 150gb for the first time. Actually many said its about 50gb. Later i tried  downloaded the android 4.0.0_r1 i have got just 20gb. but some folders got installed with bionic.git like that.There is no envsetup.sh file inside build.git folder and another issue was all files got downloaded in the platform folder not into my aosp folder which i set for download.can any one provide clear steps to download the source?

Comment: The part of your question about Android 4 is unclear. Please specify which commands you used to download the code.